# Tensorflow for Poets - Error while running retrain script (Windows 10)

Tags: tensorflow

After all the installing instructions, I'm currently trying the codelab Tensorflow for poets and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Image directory '' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\USER\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py", line 989, in main
class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Then I get all the 'is not recognized as an internal or external command' errors:

```
(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
'--bottleneck_dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
'--how_many_training_steps' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
'--model_dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
'--summaries_dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
'--output_graph' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow- for-poets-2>  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
'--output_labels' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
'--architecture' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mike\Tutorials\Beginner\tensorflow-for-poets-2>  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

when running this script:

```
python -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

[Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#1) is the reference from the codelab.

This is the route of my images folder, should it be needed. 
[image: Images route]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my shell didn't recognized the "\" as a way of adding  new line.

Also, in Windows instead of using

```
"${ARCHITECTURE}"
```

I used

```
"%ARCHITECTURE%"
```

both for the SET part and the script. In the end my script ended up looking like this:

```
python -m scripts.retrain --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks --how_many_training_steps=500 --model_dir=tf_files/models/ --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"%ARCHITECTURE%" --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --architecture="%ARCHITECTURE%" --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

Comment: The command is in Linux style. To make it Windows, remove the backslash and you can write it all in a single line like above.